# Downloading a video file of 1.x MB size takes more than 30 secs with AFNetworking 1.0

Tags: objective-c, ios7, afnetworking

I am using below code to download video files from server on my device, but it takes more than 30 secs to download a file of `1.5 MB` size. Is there any way to speed up this download process?
Like can we divide the whole video file in chunks and download them in parallel?

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"m.mp4"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:outputPath append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", outputPath);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error downloading file");

}];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Either your connection or the server may limit you to that rate. Splitting up will make it slower and is hardly possible at all.

Comment: ok... for now we changed our video files resolution from 480 * 480 to 300 * 300 on server and it improved the performance.